# Bluetooth Broadcasting (BlueNRG-2)

Tags: microcontroller, antenna, bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, st

I have a few questions regarding the use of the BlueNRG-2 device

I am building a system where I have to send small data packets (10 bytes) from 1 unit to 10+ units. I am aware that you can only have 7 simultaneous connections, but I am wondering if there is a way to broadcast this information, and have anything that is within range receive and interpret the data.

-if so, does anyone happen to have a code sample they would be willing to share?

Do you need an antenna for BLE to function? The range only needs to be about 5-10ft.

Other than the BlueNRG-2 module, is there any supporting circuitry that is necessary for functionality? I need this to fit on a PCB that is 12mm x 12mm so space is very limited

Thanks in advance

Comment: BLE does have the concept of "advertising" but it may be that you should look instead towards more direct usage of the underlying radio.  Probably in either way you want a BLE MCU with a custom firmware not a "canned product".  You'll probably end up with a "chip antenna".  Your posting doesn't really map well to the format of a stack exchange site, you may do better trading ideas on a more traditional forum.

Comment: ST has application examples for the BlueNRG. These will show you what support circuitry is needed. You're almost certainly going to need an antenna of some sort, but there are some tiny ones like [this chip antenna](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/johanson-technology-inc/2450AT14A0100T/712-1636-2-ND/7943534) for example. BLE advertising is probably the way to go to 'broadcast' a small amount of data to many devices.

Comment: I've reviewed the datasheet but I'm still not sure what can be omitted. Does it need external oscillators? I'm trying to strip it down to the bare minimum, leaving only 100% necessary components for data transmission (such as a chip antenna) . Everything has to fit on a pcb the size of a nickel, so I need to know what can be trimmed safely.